# Greedily match all routes in Rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I would like to greedily match all routes, no matter the depth. I can do this for the first tier of routes until the first '/' with

```
get '*foo', to: 'home#index'
```

the `*foo` seems to be necessary as the parser won't accept just `*`.

The parser will also not accept the common `**/*` for recursive matching. Any thoughts?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not sure what the problem is: `get '*foo', to: 'home#index'` should capture any request, even with slashes in it. See the [documentation on route globbing](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html#route-globbing).

Comment: It turns out there is an issue with the client side framework's router causing this to issue.